# Svg with width and height equal to 1px has a wrong path position

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit

Live example: https://codepen.io/Ni55aN/pen/jJGVYe

```
svg {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.cont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
svg .main-path {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke: steelblue;
}

.invalid {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

.invalid .main-path {
    stroke: red;
}
```

Equal paths are placed in different SVGs. SVG is placed in container that have an absolute position. The paths should match visually, but we have problems in SVG with a 1px height and width - the path is shifted (possibly scaled).

Why it happens? Is this a bug? And how can this be solved so that the SVG itself does not occupy any area

Comment: interesting. some things I found where that it only seems to be the `height` that is affecting this and if you add `line-height: 0` to the `.cont` it does get closer... but still off

Comment: @zgood with line-height: 0; it has a small mismatch

Comment: If you add `outline:1px solid` to your svg elements you'll be able to see that the 2 svg elements are not aligned. As @SusanSanz mentions adding `display:block` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand exactly why but you can solve it adding a display property as `flex`, `block` or `grid`:

```
svg { 
   display: flex;
}
```

I have forked your codefile [here](https://codepen.io/susanasanz9/pen/QoqddX?editors=1100)

Comment: position: absolute also fix it, but it is a bit strange

Comment: Yes. And idea... could be some hidden padding on svgs to prevent moiré effect on images for thin paths as 1px... ?

Comment: there is a problem with different zoom in a browser